# Baby Rudin Theorem 3.20 on sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Part (b) of the theorem states that "If $p>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}p^{1/n}=1.$"

Here is the $p\ge1$ case that Rudin proves:

> If $p\ge1$, put $x_n=p^{1/n}-1\ge0.$ By the binomial theorem we have $1+nx_n\le(1+x_n)^n=p.$ We then have$$0\le x_n\le \frac{p-1}{n}$$ and $x_n\to 0.$

He then states that in the case for $0<p<1$, "the result is obtained by taking reciprocals." But he is using Bernoulli's inequallity and that hold for $x_n\ge -1$  and I just can't figure out how taking the reciprocal is useful. I'm certain that I am just being very thick headed but can someone spell out what he means?

Comment: If $0<p<1$ then $p=\frac{1}{q}$ where $q>1$ so $p^{1/n}=\frac{1}{q^{1/n}}\to 1$ since the statement is already proved for $q>1$

Comment: Thanks @Marios Gretsas

Comment: For what it's worth, if logarithms are allowed, the solution is easier.  For all $\displaystyle x \in \Bbb{R}, ~\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n} = 0.$  This holds, regardless of whether $x < 0, x = 0$ or $x > 0.$  Then $\displaystyle \log\left[p^{(1/n)}\right] = \frac{\log(p)}{n} ~: ~p > 0.~~$ So, as $\displaystyle n \to \infty,~~ \log\left[p^{(1/n)}\right] ~: ~p > 0$ goes to $0$.  This implies that $p^{(1/n)} ~: ~p > 0$ goes to $1$.

Comment: Use theorem 3.3 (d) to get your desired result.